# How to make input and output numbers in specific language

Tags: android, android-edittext, textview, arabic

I have an Android app.

It consists of

- two `edittext` for input (type number and date)
- two `textview` for output (one `textview` outputs number and the other one outputs date)

My device language is Arabic.

The problem is that the two input `edittext` allow English keyboard input only, and the first `textview` output gives number in English but the second `textview` output gives the date in Arabic.

How could I make all numbers arabic and independent of device language?